# How do I re-enter a sqlite database that I already created?

Tags: sql, sqlite3

I am using sqlite3 and created a new database in the terminal by using:

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

I then created some tables in this database but then I closed sqlite3. How can I re enter my test.db? Do I simply write

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

again? I dont want to try it without knowing for sure in case it overwrites my work. Sorry for the beginner question, I couldn't find out how on the web as I guess its so simple.

Comment: If you're afraid of overwriting, why not make a copy and test? `cp test.db test2.db; sqlite3 test2.db`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes,

```
sqlite3 test.db
```

opens `test.db` if it exists and lets you work with the content it contains.